# video won't pause using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, pause

I got a project that has a video that plays in a loop. Here is the html for the video tag:

```
  <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="myVid">
      <source src="River.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

I would like the video to pause after a delay, and I am trying to implement this using javascript. My javascript code:

```
    function stopVideo() {

    var vid = document.getElementById('myVid');
    vid.pause();

    }

setTimeout(stopVideo, 900);
```

This is not working. Any ideas why? Thank you.

---------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------

if it helps, the error console is giving me a message:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'vid.pause')
```

Comment: yes. this is a typo here. I'll correct it.

Comment: The null means the element is not found, indicating that the script is running before the DOM is built (ie. in head tag). Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

*Update based on new information from OP:*

The `null` means the element is not found by `getElementById()`, indicating that the script is running before the DOM is built (ie. in the head tag).

Simply run the script code like this if in head:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // code goes here
};
```

Or more the script tag to the bottom of the document before body close tag.

*Old answer -*

Before setting the timeout, make sure the video is actually playing. With a short delay of 900ms (0.9s) you can risk the timeout code triggers before the video has started playing.

To be sure the video is actually playing you can use events such as `playing` and `timeupdate`, but in `timeupdate` is likely not accurate for this scenario, so one way around is to only trigger when `playing`:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('myVid');
var reqId; // optional, prevents running more than one time

vid.addEventListener("playing", function() {
  if (!reqId) reqId = setTimeout(stopVideo.bind(this), 2000);
});

function stopVideo() {
  this.pause();
}
```

```css
video {height:200px}
```

```html
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="myVid">
  <source src="//media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine !

```js
function stopVideo() {
  var vid = document.getElementById('myVid');
  vid.pause();
}
setTimeout(stopVideo, 5000);
```

```html
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="myVid" width="400px" >
    <source src="http://mazwai.com/system/posts/videos/000/000/123/original/victor_ciurus--5d_mark_iii_magic_lantern_14_bits_raw_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

maybe, just increase the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {stopVideo()}, 900);
```